# Bootstrap carousel expand image from bottom

Tags: html, image, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am using the Bootstrap carousel in a website which is the full width of the screen with a responsive height. The problem is that due to the nature of the images I would like the images to be aligned to the bottom of the .item div, and expand from the bottom, and not from the top-left like usual. Can this be done in CSS or can it only be done in JS?

You can see the website and the code [here](http://grbbuilding.co.uk).

Answer (score 0):

You can just set `bottom: 145%` to the `img`-tag and move it to the top of the wrapping `.item`-class. The `.item, .carousel-inner, .carousel`-classes will need a fix `height`-property to make it work.

Like this:

```
.carousel, .carousel-inner, .item {
   height:100%;
   max-height:600px;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img, 
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 145%;
}
```

Just play around with the property to find the best position.

Comment: Adding that isn't shifting the image in any way for me

Comment: Ok sorry, I missed some parts. You have to add `height: 600px` to the `.item` and `.carousel-inner`-class. Because the elements need a fixed height. I will update my answer.

Comment: I don't want the images to have a fixed height, as I want it to adjust for different window and screen sizes.

Comment: Still not working well for me as when you make the window smaller, and all of the image needs to be viewed there is a gap at the bottom